# ImageMagick and OpenJPEG2

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, imagemagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick with JP2 compatibility but I cannot seem to be able to do that.

I installed the OPenJPEG2 delegate from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/, Downloaded the latest ImageMagick and when I run ./configure I get the following:

```
 Delegate Library Configuration:
  BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes            yes
  Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no         no
  DJVU              --with-djvu=yes             no
  DPS               --with-dps=yes              no
  FFTW              --with-fftw=yes             no
  FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes              no
  FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes       no
  FreeType          --with-freetype=yes         yes
  Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=no             no
  Graphviz          --with-gvc=yes              no
  JBIG              --with-jbig=yes             yes
  JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes             yes
  LCMS              --with-lcms=yes             no
  LQR               --with-lqr=yes              no
  LTDL              --with-ltdl=yes             no
  LZMA              --with-lzma=yes             yes
  Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes yes
  OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes          no
  OpenJP2           --with-openjp2=yes          no
  PANGO             --with-pango=yes            no
  PERL              --with-perl=no              no
  PNG               --with-png=yes              yes
  RAQM              --with-raqm=yes             no
  RSVG              --with-rsvg=no              no
  TIFF              --with-tiff=yes             yes
  WEBP              --with-webp=yes             yes
  WMF               --with-wmf=yes              yes
  X11               --with-x=                   yes
  XML               --with-xml=yes              yes
  ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes             yes
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I always get `OpenJP2 --with-openjp2=yes       no`

Please can someone explain how can I install ImageMagick with OpenJP2 support on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I'm under the same problem, seems to be related to openjpeg 2.1, but I'm still running to figure out how to install it under ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Googleing I found that this is related to openjpeg 2.1

I got right now the openjp2 **YES**. If I'm not missing anything, the steps that I took was:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
wget https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/archive/version.2.1.tar.gz
tar xzf version.2.1.tar.gz
cd openjpeg-version.2.1/
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
make
sudo make install


wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xzf ImageMagick.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.9.3-8
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-modules --with-perl=/usr/bin/perl --with-jp2 --enable-shared --disable-static --without-magick-plus-pus
make
sudo make install

convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES
```